# SQL select distinct with unique ids

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm sorry, my SQL is a bit rusty so this might be trivial, but I can't figure it out.

I have table data similar to this:

```
ID  LABEL
101 A
102 A
103 A
104 B
105 C
106 C
```

I'd like to select only distinct labels, but also have a column with ids. Ideally result could be:

```
ID  LABEL
101 A
104 B
105 C
```

I don't really care which ID gets selected for a label. Less ideally id could any unique integer, like this:

```
ID  LABEL
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

I'm using SQLite, if that matters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This query will do the trick and select you the min id for each label.  You just need to put in the name of your table...

```
SELECT MIN(id), LABEL
FROM table 
GROUP BY LABEL
ORDER BY MIN(id)
```